# Django - Display "Model Object" in the admin page instead of Object title

Tags: django, unicode, model, admin

As displayed in the image it displays "Lecture Object" instead of the Lecture's title. As I've understood it, **unicode** should take care of this, but it doesn't seem to here.

Here is my **unicode** method:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: What is your python version? Run `python --version` in your console

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To display a custom string as your Model's object representation, you should:

In Python 2.x

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.some_attr  # What you want to show
```

In Python 3.x

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.some_attr  # What you want to show
```

Comment: Ah, I see! I am using python 3 so I should've been using __str__. Thanks for that.